# Scala - java.exe accessing internet?

Tags: java, scala

Hm, so I set up Scala in order to start learning it.
When I compile a .scala script, though (i.e. "scala whatever.scala" in the terminal), java.exe is accessing the internet?

Why? Is that intended behaviour or did I forget to configure something?

The script I run was fairly simple, if that should matter:

```
args.forall(println)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's accessing the internet rather than e.g. using a local network socket to communicate between one part of itself and another?

Comment: What do you mean by "accessing the Internet"? What *exactly* is it doing? Opening a socket? Downloading a file? Sending an email? How did you determine that it *is*, in fact, accessing "the Internet" and not just using an Internet protocol to talk to some other component on your PC? Are you using `fsc`, the Fast Scala Compiler, which stays in memory and gets its commands via a local network socket? Note that the `scala` script runner uses `fsc` by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that Scala compilation happens inside a Java JVM. So when you compile Scala, the java command is executed.

Java JRE has a mecanism to update itself. When a new version is out, it asks the users (at least on windows?) if they want to install the new version.

It is possible that everytime a java command is launched, it checks for updates (?)

---

**Edit**: it is possible that this is because in some cases you are using a "compile server" for Scala. This means an extra JVM is spawned just for compilation and is kept alive after your initial compilation. Then next compilation will be faster because the compilation server will already have been started and all the classes will be loaded.

It is possible that a client JVM is communicating to the compilation server JVM by using a network protocol.

Check some links:

- http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/12/28/a-new-way-to-compile/
- https://github.com/typesafehub/zinc

Comment: Don't think so. If it were, shouldn't the firewall have protested a long time ago whenever I executed "java ...", which it didn't? Is there a way to check that, though?

Comment: @User1291 maybe it's because of a compilation server. It is the case by default in Intellij I think. Check my edit